# How to store node.js object from npm package in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, npm

I am beginner in nodejs. I am using [`merkle-tools`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merkle-tools) in my meteor application. I am creating an object of class `MerkleTools`.

```
var merkleObj = new MerkleTools();
```

Is this possible to store this object `merkleObj` in MongoDB? So at require time, I can retrieve the stored object from DB and call its function like `addLeaf()` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tree has to be serialized before you store it in a database. Library you are using doesn't have such an option but you can easily do it yourself.

The following code assumes you are using this module  [https://www.npmjs.com/package/merkle-tools](http://www.npmjs.com/package/merkle-tools)

Serialize function:

```
const serializeTree = (tree) => {
  const len = tree.getLeafCount();
  const serialized = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // If you want to save binary data remove .toString('hex');
    serialized.push(tree.getLeaf(i).toString('hex'));
  }

  return serialized;
}
```

You get an array that you can easily store in a database.

When restoring the tree from the database you can do the following:

```
const makeTree = (serialized) => {
  const len = serialized.length;
  const tree = new MerkleTools();

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tree.addLeaf(serialized[i]);
  }

  tree.makeTree();

  return tree;
}
```

Returned value from the makeTree function is a merkleTools tree so you can use the methods like `.addLeaf()` to it.